# Monopoly: Do I Collect Rent If I Am In Jail?

Tags: monopoly

I am playing Monopoly and I land on the 'Go to jail' space.
The player next in line rolls, and lands on Park Place, which I own. He challenges me, and says that he doesn't have to pay rent, because I am in jail.
Is this true?

Comment: Pardon my dyslexic tendencies, but for a solid five seconds I thought this question was titled, "Monopoly: Do I Collect Rent If I Am A Jedi?"

Comment: @TheSpartan Only matters when playing star wars monopoly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being in jail prevents you from *moving.* It doesn't prevent you from doing anything else.

You can [buy property (at auction)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8784/is-it-legal-to-buy-property-for-1-in-monopoly-when-other-players-are-in-prison/10857#10857), trade properties, build houses and hotels, and yes, collect rent.

Unless there is a "house rule" against these moves, usually against the last one.

Answer (score 95):

Being in jail only prevents you from moving, and does not prevent you from doing any other action, including collecting rent. The [rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf) state:

> Even though you are in Jail, you may buy and sell property, buy
>   and sell houses and hotels and collect rents.

This is a very popular strategy late in the game, as the less you move, the less likely you are to land on your opponent's properties.

In addition, the rules specify that the only times you do not pay rent is when the property is mortgaged or if the property owner does not ask for rent before the next player's turn.

Comment: See also, [How to Win at Monopoly and Lose All Your Friends](https://imgur.com/gallery/vX3zm)

Comment: The only winning move is to not play.

Comment: "_This is a very popular **strategy** late in the game_" I know it's been many years since I played Monopoly, but surely this can only be "_a bit of good fortune_" and not a "_strategy_"? As far as I can remember, you can't _plan_ on being sent to jail, can you?

Comment: @TripeHound you can't plan on being sent to jail, but you can try to stay in jail longer by choosing to attempt to roll doubles instead of paying $50 to get out immediately.

Comment: You can't gaurantee you will end up there but when you do end up there (and statistically you probablly will) you have to choose whether to buy yourself out. In the early game it makes sense to buy your way out so that you can collect your salery and buy properties. In the late game it makes sense to stay in jail as long as possible because landing on other people's properties costs you money.

Comment: @YoungJohn (and @PeterGreen) that makes sense... I assumed mmathis meant trying to be _sent_ there, instead of trying to _stay_ there.

Comment: @TripeHound: You may also have the option of whether or not to play a *Get Out Of Jail Free* card, if you hold one :)

Comment: @psmears you sell the get out of jail free card to someone in jail for $25

Comment: @curiousdannii Naw that's tic-tac-toe

Answer (score 49):

Not being able to collect rent is just one of many fairly common [house rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Monopoly/House_Rules#Rents_and_auctions).

> Some house rules disqualify an owner from collecting rent while in jail. This allows reprieve for other players landing on an expensive property with houses or a hotel during the time a player is incarcerated.

While this is not an official rule, some people choose to play by this house rule.

Comment: One of the many house rules that makes the game take much longer and be more painful then intended.

Comment: All Monopoly house rules are evil.

Comment: Wonder if this house rule is more common in states or countries where inmates are not allowed to vote.

Comment: @NuclearWang Most. I always play with the "rent collection is not optional" and "must pay rent with assets on hand" rules to discourage collusion and make it easier to bankrupt players.

Comment: I thought monopoly was intended to be long and painful. So the house rule fits the spirit of the game

Comment: @OganM: If you and all of your fellow players agree that you want to play a long and painful game, that's your choice, but personally I would not like to play such a game (so I try to avoid Monopoly altogether, natch).

Comment: @OganM People often play with house rules. These house rules are, by and large, toxic. In the standard game of monopoly the cash supply decreases over time. If you look at the chance cards for instance, they take away money more often than giving it. House rules often seek to increase the supply (ex land on free parking, get money) and this draws out the game drastically.

Comment: @OganM Monopoly is intended to be painful but not long. The game is supposed to give one player an early and commanding lead which continues until they force all other players out. House rules are what make the game longer, like ignoring the auction rule or money for free parking.